# Using Push Notes Find Out If App deleted

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, push-notification

I am using Push Notification for my IOS APP. I just want to know using push notes can we find out that app is deleted from device or not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple provides a feed back service for this [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3) is a link to the documentation, basically you can use their feedback service to check if push notification tokens are still valid... hope this helps

Daniel